# Eclipse empty parameter string

Tags: java, eclipse, parameters, applet

In the menu Run->Run Configurations of a Java Applet under the tab Parameters, you can't add a parameter whose value is empty. How can I use an empty string as parameter for a Java Applet in Eclipse?

The parameters are retrieved in the Applet with getParameter(name);

Here's a screenshot of the parameter tab:
[image]

Comment: You mean **Arguments** tab because I am not finding **Parameter** tab in run configuration. Add the screen shot better understanding. You can share screen shot here http://postimg.org/

Comment: There is a parameter tab.

Comment: Add full screen shot below part is not visible I just wanted to check whether it has **Variable..** button?

Comment: No idea. Try with ""(Empty double quotes), Single space character and a space character between double quotes. Click on **Add** button and check in the popup dialog will get **Variable...** atleast